# I'm new to command line. I get a lot of messages like 'command not found' and 'no such file or directory'

Tags: google-app-engine, command-line, filepath, gcloud

Trying to run `gcloud init` to initialize the Google App Engine Engine SDK by typing `./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init` but it showed: `no such file or directory` or `command not found`. Is something wrong with my PATH?  My path is: 
`/Users/AnneLutz/Documents/google-cloud-sdk\`

Answer (score 0):

If you typing `./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init` and you installed Cloud SDK in `/Users/AnneLutz/Documents/google-cloud-sdk`, then your current directory should be `/Users/AnneLutz/Documents` in order for what you type to work.

That said you should add `/Users/AnneLutz/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/bin` to you path. To do this, assuming you are using `bash` you can

```
source /Users/AnneLutz/Documents/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc
```

To make it so that every-time you start your shell you can add it to shell profile. For example you can add above source command at the end of `~/.bash_profile` file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you used the option to download the SDK zip file and are then trying to configure your environment with that download option. If you aren't comfortable with setting environment variables, you might want to instead try installing using the "interactive" installer, which will automate the steps for making the commands always available on your system.

The directions are [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#interactive), but for Mac OS users are basically:

1. Enter the following at a command prompt:

   ```
   curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
   ```
2. Restart your shell:

   ```
   exec -l $SHELL
   ```
3. Run gcloud init to initialize the gcloud environment:

   ```
   gcloud init
   ```

For many, this procedure is easier than getting everything configured manually.

Comment: Brett! It worked!!! Wow, I'm impressed. Thank you SO much for your help.